# CSP nonce support in React custom library

Tags: reactjs, content-security-policy, rollup, rollupjs, nonce

I have created a custom React library and bundled it using Rollup.
I am using the Styles plugin to bundle CSS files in Rollup. The project that is consuming this library has a nonce attribute in the `meta` tag of `head` and I want the `CSP-NONCE` value to be populated into the `style` tags injected by the custom library so that it won't get blocked by CSP when it's enabled.

I have tried writing a script which run on `DOMContentLoaded` event to inject the value of meta tag into the `style` tags, but it's still blocking.

How can I add nonce value in `style` tag injected by custom library at consumer side?